# inappropriate error when creating index on oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

I am running below command to `create` an `index` on the `table` of oracle ebs.

```
create index mtl_index_N1 on MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS(last_update_date);
```

But I am getting error which does not seems correct with `index`. what is this issue? is error related with Database indexes or `sqldeveloper` issue?

[image]

Comment: Well the error says you're trying to do that for a view. Are you sure MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS is really a table? Maybe it should be a materialized view?

Comment: That seems to be a standard table; so are you connected as the EBS schema owner, or as a different user that maybe has a view (or is hitting a synonym) against the real table? What do you see if you `select user, owner, object_type from all_objects where object_name = 'MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS` - can you add the output of that to your question?

Comment: Incidentally, are you sure you want to build an index on LAST_UPDATE_DATE? Indexes on just a date column normally have a limited utility. A function-based index on `trunc(last_update_date)` to remove the time element might be more useful.

Comment: Don't create indexes without tablespace parameter(in EBS  indexes have their own tablespaces or create new tablespace).It's a synonym in `APPS` schema and table in `INV` schema. `create index mtl_index_N1 on INV.MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS(last_update_date) idx_tablespace_name;`

Comment: To expand a bit on @APC's comment, unless many of the queries on the table were of the nature of "What rows were updated in the last three days, or during the month  of June?" Then when there is frequently a criteria of a *date range* would an index be helpful.